# ¿Usar SELECT * en consultas SQL es una mala práctica?

Tags: sql, buenas-prácticas

No lo he leído en ninguna parte, pero por sentido común considero que escribir consultas así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla;
```

es una **mala práctica**.

Para mí el motivo principal de considerarlo mala práctica es que posiblemente estaremos seleccionando columnas que nunca usaremos. Es más, aún en el caso de que necesitemos todas las columnas no lo usaría nunca, porque la tabla puede evolucionar con el tiempo (se le agregan más columnas) y estaremos incurriendo en lo mismo.

Lo que quiero saber a través de esta pregunta es si hay más motivos **demostrables** (no meras opiniones), por los que el uso de `SELECT *` sea una mala práctica y si estos están documentados en alguna parte.

O... si hay motivos contundentes para afirmar lo contrario, que sí es una buena práctica o podría serlo al menos en algunos casos.

> **NOTA:** La pregunta está orientada a un uso de `SELECT *` **en programas finale**s, no a datos de prueba durante el desarrollo/depuración de programas.

Comment: es mala práctica sólo cuando el código está en producción...si estás explorando datos, no es necesariamente un problema

Comment: es mala practica si no sabes que campos tenes.. en una tabla id,descripcion, es exactamente lo mismo...

Comment: @Lamak podriamos llegar a estar horas dando ejemplos de cuando si y cuando no, no?

Comment: lo que pasa con esto es que cada vez que aras una cosulta tambien te traera datos que no son necesarios y que solo se ocupan para comparativas , como son los id, campos fk y demas.Como dicen arriba si estas explorando datos es bueno usar `select * from`, pero ya en produccion deberian especificarse las columnas.

Comment: El dato de @Lamak es importante. La pregunta está orientada a programas finales, no a programas, en desarrollo. Es claro que todos lo usamos cuando probamos datos. Editaré la pregunta con ese detalle.

Comment: lo que pasa es que cuando utilizamos el `select * from` impide el uso efectivo de indices, además genera mas trabajo a la base de datos esas consultas.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez que tienen que ver los indices con los campos que traes, si los indices se usan para filtrar las filas, no las columnas...

Comment: lo que pasa que esa es una de las desventajas de utilizar select *.Solo lo quise aclarar, nada mas.

Comment: estas respuestas no sirven como respuesta? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25093187/73749

Comment: o esta: todavia mejor https://stackoverflow.com/q/65512/73749

Comment: @gbianchi O esta [otra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180375/select-vs-select-column)

Comment: @gbianchi [el artículo](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/the-real-reason-select-queries-are-bad-index-coverage) al que enlaza la pregunta última que refieres parece interesante. Y en el mismo hay algunos comentarios muy esclarecedores, como por ejemplo uno que habla sobre el problema añadido de las Vistas al usar `SELECT *`

Comment: aca hay un ejemplo: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/102403/76301 que contradice totalmente todas las respuestas.

Comment: y mas ejemplos (este sitio es bueno): https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-08/its-not-about-the-star-stupid

Comment: @gbianchi no entendí bien la respuesta aceptada. Y allí se trata de una consulta que implica un `ORDER BY`. Hay un comentario que dice que si se colocan las columnas en el mismo orden en que están en la tabla, no hay ninguna diferencia de rendimiento. Y otro comentario dice que ejecutar dos consultas una detrás de la otra puede afectar el rendimiento de la segunda consulta.

Comment: Lo que esta diciendo, es que esa base de datos en particular, tiene problemas al desordenar las columnas porque tiene que ordenarlas, entonces pierde tiempo con eso. entonces en ese caso, * funciona mejor, salvo que pases las columnas en el orden exacto en que estan en la descripcion de la tabla. y los otros comentarios no dicen mucho mas.

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta seria: es malo? depende... hay que usarlo? depende.. en que casos? depende... es como demasiado amplia, habria que ver casi caso por caso. Hay que evitarlo? y tambien depende...

Comment: Ojo.. sigo pensando que la pregunta no es mala.. pero la respuesta deberia ser medio libro...

Comment: Mis dos centavos sobre el tema: Me inclino mas en pesar que es mejor evitar usarlo, justamente porque a la hora de hacer un `script` uno sabe que campos necesita. Si posteriormente se _agregan o quitan campos a las tablas involucradas y el `script` no los necesita no pasa nada_, es decir, no debería cambiar el resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Un `SELECT *` no es una buena práctica, ya que como tú lo mencionas este devuelve todas las columnas de la tabla, haciendo que si se tiene un gran número de filas de dicha tabla, el tamaño de los datos transportados por la red probablemente impactará al rendimiento de la aplicación ya en **producción**, si fuese en una fase de prueba no habría problema, pero como estamos hablando de aplicaciones finales si seria un inconveniente. Es por ello que es importante siempre trabajar toda consulta `Query` con una condición utilizando la clausula `WHERE` y evitar problemas de rendimiento cuando los datos de nuestra tabla sean extensos.

Answer (score 2):

Un punto importante de por qué usar `SELECT *` cuando no necesitamos todas las columnas de las tablas es mala práctica tiene relación con que dificulta el uso de los índices. Esto porque lo más lógico es que el índice no incluya todas las columnas de una tabla, y si estás usando `SELECT *`, significa que una vez que encuentras las filas usando el índice, debes hacer un lookup a la tabla de vuelta para encontrar el resto de las columnas y entregarlas.

Este proceso es costoso, y en muchas ocasiones puede ser menos costoso simplemente recorrer la tabla de una vez y no usar el índice

Otro ejemplo que puede traer problemas y que he visto más de una vez es usar `SELECT *` en vistas, y esto puede traer las siguientes situaciones, prueba el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1(c1 int, c2 int);
GO

INSERT dbo.t1(c1,c2) 
VALUES(1,2);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.v_t1
AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM dbo.t1;
GO

-- qué pasa si hacemos cambios a la tabla?
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.t1.c2', N'c3', N'COLUMN';

ALTER TABLE dbo.t1 ADD c2 date 
    NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE();

ALTER TABLE dbo.t1 ADD c4 uniqueidentifier 
    NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID();
GO

-- la vista muestra data incorrecta
SELECT * FROM dbo.t1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.v_t1;
GO

EXEC sys.sp_refreshview @viewname = N'dbo.v_t1';
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.v_t1;
```

[**Acá podemos**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d55d744c5982e5bbec5a15f04138c3a) ver que la usar `SELECT *` en la vista y luego hacer cambios en la tabla base, éstos no se ven reflejados hasta que se ejecuta el refresh de la vista...y esto puede ser catastrófico en producción.

Answer (score 1):

Usar SELECT * no es mala practica, eso depende de como lo uses, si el motivo es para no especificar los campos en los que estás interesado, eso sería una mala practica, en cambio si al realizar la consulta por alguna razon necesitas todos los campos de la tabla es correcto usar SELECT *

Comment: sip , pero que pasa con el rendimiento?, se supone que cuando nosotros ejecutamos un select * , primero sql lee la estructura y luego hace la consulta, que es diferente que cuando especificamos.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez depende de tu conjunto de datos, como te imaginarás si tienes una única tupla el rendimiento es practicamente el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Usar Select * no es una buena practica en los casos que no necesites todas las columnas de la tabla ya que estarías trayendo elementos innecesarios en la consulta con el consecuente consumo de recursos, te dejo este [articulo](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-faster-SELECT-*-or-SELECT-by-column-names-in-MySQL) que indica otras razones.